# Modelling leadtime in cplex (Production Planning Problem)

Tags: indexing, cplex

[Constraint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqXXt.png)

For this problem, I would like to model out this constraint in cplex.But I am not sure if the indexes that I put is correct or not. Can anyone help me to explain if I did it wrong. Here are some of my codes:

```
Data:
Products = {P1 P2 P3};
NbOperations = 10;
NbPeriods = 3;
LeadTime = [1,1,3,5,0,0,3,0,0,0];

{string} Products = ...;
int NbOperations = ...; range Operations = 1..NbOperations;
int NbPeriods = ...; range Periods = 1..NbPeriods;
int LeadTime[Operations]= ...;

dvar int+ Y[Products][0..NbOperations][Periods];
dvar int+ Xin[Products][-4..NbPeriods];
  forall(p in Products,l in Operations,t in Periods)
  ct3:
    Xin[p][t-LeadTime[l]] == Y[p][l][t];
```

The LeadTime is the estimated lead time of l operation of product p. In my case, I am assuming the lead time is the same for all products.

I felt like the -4 there is wrong. But, I don't know how to change it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can also slice and then you do not have to write -4

```
{string} Products = ...;
int NbOperations = ...; range Operations = 1..NbOperations;
int NbPeriods = ...; range Periods = 1..NbPeriods;
int LeadTime[Operations]= ...;

dvar int+ Y[Products][0..NbOperations][Periods];
dvar int+ Xin[Products][1..NbPeriods];

subject to
{
  forall(p in Products,l in Operations,t in Periods:(t-LeadTime[l]) in 1..NbPeriods)
  ct3:
    Xin[p][t-LeadTime[l]] == Y[p][l][t];
  }
```